# Devstack - Pike - No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available. - code 500 - Failure Checking if device /dev/kvm is accessible

Tags: cloud, openstack, host, openstack-nova, devstack

I got this error while I was working with DEVSTACK.

I successfully installed Devstack based on the latest stable version (Pike) and when i tried to launch an instance I got the error message "message: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available. code: 500".

I tried to execute the `virt-host-validate` command with the result shown below:

```
:~$ virt-host-validate
QEMU: Checking for hardware virtualization                                 : PASS
QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm exists                                   : PASS
QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm is accessible                            : FAIL (Check /dev/kvm is world writable or you are in a group that is allowed to access it)
QEMU: Checking if device /dev/vhost-net exists                             : PASS
QEMU: Checking if device /dev/net/tun exists                               : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller mount-point                  : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller mount-point                     : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller mount-point                 : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller mount-point                  : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller mount-point                 : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller mount-point                   : PASS
QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support                         : PASS
QEMU: Checking if IOMMU is enabled by kernel                               : WARN (IOMMU appears to be disabled in kernel. Add intel_iommu=on to kernel cmdline arguments)
LXC: Checking for Linux >= 2.6.26                                         : PASS
LXC: Checking for namespace ipc                                           : PASS
LXC: Checking for namespace mnt                                           : PASS
LXC: Checking for namespace pid                                           : PASS
LXC: Checking for namespace uts                                           : PASS
LXC: Checking for namespace net                                           : PASS
LXC: Checking for namespace user                                          : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller mount-point                  : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller mount-point                     : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller mount-point                 : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller mount-point                  : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller mount-point                 : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
LXC: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller mount-point                   : PASS
```

Any tips to solve the failure got while "Checking if device /dev/kvm is accessible"?

I tried, without success, following the tips in this page "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation"

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

The following question could be very useful: "https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/92701/no-valid-host-was-found-there-are-not-enough-hosts-available"

Comment: I think it might not be the cause, but which flavor are you trying to use and how big is the machine you install devstack on?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @vabada . I tried using several flavors (m1.small, m1.medium, m1.large) but with the same results (ERROR STATE). My machine has about 55GB of free RAM and 32GB of free memory.

Comment: Do you have any tips?